# SUPEE-9767 v2 can't be applied

Tags: patches, security, magento1.9.2.4, supee-9767

I'm trying to install ***SUPEE-9767*** but it failed with the following return :

---

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 138.

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php.rej

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 222.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 308.

2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php.rej
```

---

I tried to replace those files with github one but it won't work either.

I also read about missing ***SUPEE-7405*** but it was needed prior to Magento 1.9.2.4 (which is my release)

And I don't get debug message about saving rejects. Couldn't find these files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install manually, you can find your magento patch files here

https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-9767-without-ssh/

Comment: Thank's it worked this way

Comment: **never download patches from untrusted third party sources!** The only official source is https://magento.com/tech-resources/download (release archives, scroll down to patches)

Comment: @Fabian Schmengler. Sure but magento won't provide any other way to apply patch but a sh file which won't work

Comment: "Never install patches from third parties",  "But....". " NO but. NEVER install parches from third parties".

Comment: Sorry @Marius I didnot get your comment

Comment: It was supposed to mimic a conversation. THe idea is to never install patches from other sources than Magento as Fabian said.

Comment: Magentary is an active Disqus user. Look ok to me. And better install patch this way than no patch at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will check [magereport.com](https://www.magereport.com/) any patches are missing. if missing please apply that patches.

Download the what your version using and and compare the file any space or any code change in that file.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
```